# What happens to a shiny app when you close the browser window?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Or to ask the question in a different way: *Can you run shiny apps in the background without the app being explicitly accessed by a browser.*

My use case. I would like to refresh a data file stored on the hard disk every day. To do this, I can use `invalidateLater()`. However, do I explicitly need to have this app open in a browser window for it to work? Do I have to initialise the app by opening it in a browser window for it to work?

Comment: can you do that in a [cron](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/) job?

Comment: yes, it is possible I guess to run a cron job against the Rscript which updates the data daily.

Comment: I use stopApp() function in server.R to stop the app in the middle of the night. Then I load/update my DB with the new day (yesterday) and restart the app by simply running another R script with runApp() at later time.